# while running my app it's giving error "context initialization failed"

Tags: java, spring, maven

while running my spring security application i'm getting the error.

This is the Error Stack

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name   '(inner bean)#18': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type   [org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl] while setting bean property   'accessDeniedHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#20': Error setting property values; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
  PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'errorPage'   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: errorPage must begin with     '/'at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean    (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:279)at   springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary  (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean  (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 40 more





  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0':    Cannot create inner bean '(inner   bean)' of type   [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] while setting   constructor   argument with key [9]; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)  #18': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type     [org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl] while setting bean property     'accessDeniedHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:     Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#20': Error setting property values; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
  PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'errorPage'   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: errorPage must begin with    '/'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean  (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:279)
    at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary  (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList  (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:350)
    at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary  (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments  (ConstructorResolver.java:623)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor  (ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference  (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: add some more info, just stack trace won't help.

Comment: From the error stack it can be determined that the errorPage value is invalid. Can you check what is the value passed for that

Comment: Thanks...i just missed forward slash to perform a redirect

Comment: @Sunny actually, the error message in the stack trace seems pretty intuitive to understand

Answer (score 1):

In the stack trace it's said `errorPage must begin with    '/'`

You need to modify the entry in your `*-security.xml` file:

```
<security:access-denied-handler error-page="/<Your error page controller name>" />
```

Example:

```
<security:access-denied-handler error-page="/MyPage.htm" />
```

Error page must always start with "/"